# TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest

Here are the codes

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');

var databaseName = 'Starter',
    collectionName = 'wines';

var Server = mongo.Server,
    Db = mongo.Db,
    BSON = mongo.BSONPure;

db = new Db(databaseName, server);

db.open(function(err, db) {
  if(!err) {
    console.log("Connected to 'winedb' database");
    db.collection(collectionName, {strict:true}, function(err, collection) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("The 'wines' collection doesn't exist. Creating it with sample data...");
            populateDB();
        }
    });
  }
});

exports.findById = function(req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  console.log('Retrieving wine: ' + id);

  db.collection(collectionName, function(err, collection) {
      collection.findOne({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, function(err, item) {
          res.send(item);
      });
  });

};
```

These codes are based on a sample of restful api for nodejs with mongoDB.
However, it seems that it cannot recognise the function `findOne`. Can someone point out the problem?

Error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined
```

Comment: Do you actually see the `wines` collection in the DB?

Comment: Make sure you always check for errors.

Comment: The other thing about the errors.  Not finding the collection will still (at least the last time I tried something like this) return an empty array, but no error.

Comment: Which version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: the `wines` are there. I just cannot use the findOne function to get the data

Comment: You should be using `MongoClient` instead of directly creating `Server` and `Db` objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `findOne` is deprecated in the latest version of mongodb@2.x

https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2.0/lib/collection.js

You can use this query instead

```
find(query).limit(1).next(function(err, doc){
   // handle data
})
```

Comment: It's bizarre that they're deprecating `findOne` when they just changed from `update` to `updateOne` and `updateMany` and deprecated `update`! That said, `findOne` is still there for now so I don't see how this actually fixes anything.

Answer (score 0):

In the first `db.collection` you send 3 arguments like:

`db.collection(collectionName, {strict:true}, function(err, collection)`

After you only send 2:

`db.collection(collectionName, function(err, collection)`

This should be your issue.

Comment: The "options" argument is optional, so you can call it with both 2 or 3 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You represent your collection in a variable called `collectionName` and you are trying to invoke `findOne()` on something called collection which wont work.

instead of :

```
collection.findOne({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, function(err, item)
```

use:

```
collectionName.findOne({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, function(err, item)
```

Answer (score 0):

change the start of your code to

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
mongo.BSONPure = require('bson').BSONPure;

var databaseName = 'Starter',
    collectionName = 'wines';

var Server = mongo.Server,
    Db = mongo.Db,
    BSON = mongo.BSONPure;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
collection.findOne({'_id':new mongo.ObjectID(id)}, function(err, item) {
```

instead of

```
collection.findOne({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, function(err, item) {
```

in your `wine.js` file

Answer (score 0):

try to log collection to the console before using findOne or wrapping the whole thing in an:

---

`if(err){log}
else{findone}`

---

```
      if(err){
      console.log(err)
      }
      else{
      collection.findOne({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, function(err, item){
      res.send(item);
      }}
```

the reason it is not working is because `collection` in your **error-first callback** function is the parameter that gets assigned if the operation is successful ...

[Useful link about the topic ....](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/)